# How to insert multiple images in one figure using LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

I would like to insert 16 images in (4 rows and 4 columns) and display them in just one figure.

For example:

```
Img1  Img2  Img3  Img4

Img5  Img6  Img7  Img8

Img9  Img10  Img11  Img12

Img13  Img14  Img15  Img16
```

Comment: Are all the images of the same size?

Comment: Hello ! Welcome on TeX ! Please provide us a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Each of them should have its own caption and/or label, or there will be a common caption and label?

Answer (score 19):

You can just put multiple `\includegraphics` commands into your `figure` environment. Keep it mind that `figure` is just a logical, floating container which can hold basically everything which creates content, together with a `\caption` or not. Even multiple `\caption`s are not a problem.

For the alignment of the images you could use e.g. a `tabular` environment. The use of it inside a `figure` is perfectly valid even when there are usually used inside `table`. If all images should have the same width and have the same height, just place four of them in a line ended as normal with `\\` and place `\hfill` between them to fill the remaining space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example content

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}
    \\[\smallskipamount]
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}
    \\[\smallskipamount]
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}
    \\[\smallskipamount]
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Some images}\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

### [image]

If the images have different heights they are aligned at their bottom on every line. If you want to align them on top or on the vertical center the simplest way is to load the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option and add `valign=t` or `valign=c` at the end of the keylist, e.g. `\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth,valign=c]{...}`. Using `adjustbox` you can also add white margins around the images using the `margin` key or easily draw a frame around images. Please see the package manual for more details.

Answer (score 4):

one way to achieve this is a matrix of nodes using tikz:

```
    %Preamble
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}

    %Document
    \begin{tikzpicture
    \matrix[matrix of nodes]{
    \includegraphics{Img1} & \includegraphics{Img2} &\includegraphics{Img3} & 
    \includegraphics{Img4}\\
    \includegraphics{Img5} & \includegraphics{Img6} &\includegraphics{Img7} & 
    \includegraphics{Img8}\\
    \includegraphics{Img9} & \includegraphics{Img10} &\includegraphics{Img11} & 
    \includegraphics{Img12}\\
    \includegraphics{Img13} & \includegraphics{Img14} &\includegraphics{Img15} & 
    \includegraphics{Img16}\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

In order for this to look good right away the images need to have the same size (maybe use \includegraphics[width=x, keepasapectratio]{Img}). Otherwise you need some more tweaking the matrix itself.

Answer (score 1):

another way to archive this is the subfigure environment.
To use subfigures you need to `\usepackage{subcaption}`

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \vspace{-2cm}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=1, natwidth=193px,natheight=197px]{img/prinzipbild.jpg}
        \caption{Prinzipbild \cite{Tipl}}
        \label{Prinzipbild}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.5\textwidth}
        \vspace{2.8cm}
        \includegraphics[scale=1, natheight=115px,natwidth=263px]{img/realerSensor.jpg}
            \caption{Schnitt realer Sensor \cite{Pat}}
        \label{realSensor}
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Der Sensor in Theorie und Verwirklichung}
\end{figure}
```

this now places 2 figures next to each other in one row.

Do Change the

```
0.5\textwidth
```

to 0.25\textwidth and you should get the 2 figures consuming 1/4 of the available horizontal space. Add 2 more figures to get 4 figures in a row.
I guess you can add more figures and it places them automatically in another row or you may have to use \vspace and \hspace a couple of places…

Comment: It's indeed a good option. It would be a good answer if you completed the code to make it a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that people can easily compile to see the output. A screenshot would be nice too.

Comment: Can you at least add the necessary packages to compile your code fragment?

Comment: The subfigure environment needs `\usepackage{subcaption}` I've edited it