# how to insert a large number of images in latex

Tags: graphics

I am not sure whether this question has been asked here before or the question is stupid to ask due to insufficient knowledge in how latex graphics actually work.

I add a picture using \includegraphics{1.jpg} now If I have a large number of images(finite), how can I insert those images in a single command or so? I mean what is easy and quick way to insert rather than writing \includegraphics{1.jpg}, \includegraphics{2.jpg}, \dots \dots, \includegraphics{n.jpg}?

Thanks!

Edit: Just after asking the question I saw this post but not sure if it is answering my query:  [How to insert multiple images in one figure using LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471767/how-to-insert-multiple-images-in-one-figure-using-latex?rq=1)

Comment: the linked question might not do exactly what you need. What you need to do depends on what your document will look like. What I mean, is: will the images be placed on more than one page? Will you add captions? Do you need to refer to individual images in your text? Is there going to be running text between the individual images that you will add later on? In summary: a potential answerer needs more information as to what you will want to do with your document later on. Give an example of what you have in mind or (best) add an MWE so people can work on that.

Comment: Well, very simple, imagine I have 2000 images from  a trip, and I just want them to keep as a pdf book, each page will have one image say.

Comment: Do the image filenames follow a recognizable sequence (`img1`, `img2` ...) or do you intend to input a list of image names?

Comment: image files names are 1.jpg, dot dot 2000.jpg

Comment: Then I think wang's answer may suffice.

Comment: I am doing \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}


\foreach \x in {1,2,....,2000}{
    \includegraphics[height=10cm, width=10cm]{\x}
}

\end{document}

Comment: But It is not coming at all.

Comment: @Marso Your comment includes 4 dots `....` but it should only be three `...`, as in `{1,2,...,2000}`

Comment: I corrected that too. It is still not generating any pdf.

Comment: maybe due to a large number of images it is not working? Pdf is generated till 200 image though.

Comment: update: It is happening step by step, like from 200-->400-->600--->800-->100-->1200-->1400--> etc but not all the 2000 images at a time giving me 2000 page pdf ..but it works and took time to compile. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easy with foeach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2,...,3}{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{\x}%
}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Marso re your attempted edit: Not fix height and width, at most one of them. And file type is not necessary, better remove it. Latex will know which type is best